# WebClient.DownloadString(url) does not work with 2nd parameter

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I am using the WebClient.DownloadString() method to download some data. I am using the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string query = "select+%3farticle+%3fmesh+where+{+%3farticle+a+npg%3aArticle+.+%3farticle+npg%3ahasRecord+[+dc%3asubject+%3fmesh+]+.+filter+regex%28%3fmesh%2c+\"blood\"%2c+\"i\"%29+}";
        NameValueCollection queries = new NameValueCollection();
        queries.Add("query", query);
        //queries.Add("output", "sparql_json");
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            wc.QueryString = queries;
            string result = wc.DownloadString("http://data.nature.com/sparql");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

With this code, tt works fine and gives me an xml string as the output. But I would like to get a JSON output and hence I un-commented the line

```
queries.Add("output", "sparql_json");
```

and executed the same program and it seems to be fetching an error message from the server.

However, if I try to use a web browser and use the same url (as given below), it gives me a JSON as expected:
[URL that works in browsers](http://data.nature.com/sparql?query=select%20?article%20?mesh%20where%20%7B%20?article%20a%20npg%3aArticle%20.%20?article%20npg%3ahasRecord%20%5B%20dc%3asubject%20?mesh%20%5D%20.%20filter%20regex%28?mesh,%20%22blood%22,%20%22i%22%29%20%7D&output=sparql_json)

I am wondering what the problem could be. Especially when it works in a browser and not using a webclient. Is the webclient doing something different here?

Please note that I also tried to specify the query as

`query + "&output=sparql_json"`

But that does not work either.

Could someone please tell me what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: in your `string query = "..."` initialization, should you be encoding the value already?  I don't think you should be.  Put it as plain-text and let `queries.Add("query", query)` encode it for you.

Comment: Matthew, the problem is not with the query. With just the query, it works fine - it gives me an xml. But if i try to do an "&output=sparql_json" along with the query, i get an error. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be the browser fixing up a faulty query string for you automatically, pretty sure it's your query string that needs fixing.

Comment: Matthew, Thanks a lot for the comments. Apparently, as L.B suggested, I just had to include the Accept Json header and changing nothing else. The query string (encoded or not) gives me just the same result.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: Ram, please write up your change as an answer and accept it, or ask LB to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `wc.Headers.Add("Accept","application/json");`. Here is the full source I tested

```
string query = "select ?article ?mesh where { ?article a npg:Article . ?article npg:hasRecord [ dc:subject ?mesh ] . filter regex(?mesh, \"blood\", \"i\") }";
NameValueCollection queries = new NameValueCollection();
queries.Add("query", query);
queries.Add("output", "sparql_json");
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    wc.Headers.Add("Accept","application/json");
    wc.QueryString = queries;
    string result = wc.DownloadString("http://data.nature.com/sparql");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thats amazing. I have downloaded a json before but I never specified the Headers.Add("Accept","application/json"); Does it have anything to do with the server? Anyways, the solution worked. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: To add to my previous comment, the solution was to add the extra header that you suggested : wc.Headers.Add("Accept","application/json"); made all the difference. Thanks!